# String range in Scala

Tags: scala

In Ruby we can do this:

```
$ irb
>> ("aa".."bb").map { |x| x }
=> ["aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af", "ag", "ah", "ai", "aj", "ak", "al", "am", "an", "ao", "ap", "aq", "ar", "as", "at", "au", "av", "aw", "ax", "ay", "az", "ba", "bb"]
```

In Scala if I try the same I get error:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).

scala> ("aa" to "bb").map(x => x)
<console>:8: error: value to is not a member of java.lang.String
              ("aa" to "bb").map(x => x)
                    ^
```

How do get a range of Strings in Scala ?

Comment: A rather odd behaviour. How does Ruby determine you want to stop at the character 'z'?

Comment: Infact `("aB".."bZ").map{|x| x}` knows that it has to stop at `Z`. `("a0".."b9").map{|x| x}` knows that it has to stop at `9`. So there must be some alphabetic and numeric ranges which power this logic.

Answer (score 3):

For this example you could do (scala 2.10)

```
val atoz = 'a' to 'z'
for {c1 <- atoz if c1 <= 'b'; c2 <- atoz if (c1 == 'a' || (c1 == 'b' && c2 < 'c'))} yield s"$c1$c2"
```

Edited as per comment, thanks (but getting a bit ugly!)

Comment: I'd add restriction something like `c1 <- atoz if c1 <= 'b'` and it would suit initial conditions of question

Comment: would you consider following a "cleaner" solution? `def charval(x: Char, y: Char) = x * 1000 + y` and `for { c1 <- atoz; c2 <- atoz if (charval(c1,c2) <= charval('b','b'))} yield s"$c1$c2"`. More like Math but replacing "bb" with another ending string like "bk" becomes easier. A bit more readable

Answer (score 2):

```
('a' to 'z').map("a" + _) :+ "ba" :+ "bb"
```

:)

Answer (score 2):

A for comprehension would do nicely:

```
val abc = 'a' to 'z'
for (c1 <- abc; c2 <- abc) yield (s"$c1$c2")
```

This yields a Seq/Vector[String] with all the permutations you'd expect

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possibility, assuming your characters are meant to be in the range 'a' to 'z'. The `intToAlpha` function is not very pretty and not symmetric to `alphaToInt`, so one might come up with a better implementation.

```
// "a" -> 0, "b" -> 1, "ba" -> 26, "bb" -> 27 etc.
def alphaToInt(s: String) = (0 /: s) { (res, c) => res * 26 + c - 'a' }

// reverse function to `alphaToInt`
def intToAlpha(len: Int)(i: Int) = {
  val sb  = new StringBuilder
  var j   = i
  while (sb.length < len) {
    sb append ((j % 26) + 'a').toChar
    j /= 26
  }
  sb.reverse.toString
}

def range(from: String, to: String) =
  alphaToInt(from) to alphaToInt(to) map intToAlpha(from.length)
```

Test:

```
range("aa", "bb")
```

An alternative version:

```
import annotation.tailrec

@tailrec def intToAlpha(len: Int, res: String = "")(i: Int): String =
  if (len <= 0) res
  else {
    val c = ((i % 26) + 'a').toChar
    intToAlpha(len - 1, s"$c$res")(i / 26)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

It like a 26*26 matrix for every 2 char combination, imagin we have a matrix(a-z * a-z):

```
def scan(start:String, end:String) = { 

  val row_start                 = start.toCharArray.head
  val column_start_of_first_row = start.toCharArray.last
  val row_end                   = end.toCharArray.head
  val column_end_of_last_row    = end.toCharArray.last

  val printRow =
    (current_row:String, current_row_start_col:Char, current_row_end_col:Char) =>
      (current_row_start_col to current_row_end_col).map( current_row + _ ) 

  (row_start to row_end).map { current_row=>
      current_row match {
        case `row_start` => printRow(current_row.toString, column_start_of_first_row, 'z')
        case `row_end`   => printRow(current_row.toString, 'a'                      , column_end_of_last_row)
        case _           => printRow(current_row.toString, 'a'                      , 'z')                                                                                      
      }   
  }.reduce(_ ++: _)

}

println( scan("aa", "bb") )
println( scan("af", "bb") )
```